# Yosemite - Use fullscreen (as in proper fullscreen) for apps that don't support it

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I am using Mac OSX Yosemite and I actually love the green button fullscreen mode, as in, the one you get when you press the green button with the double arrows. Although that may be because when I bought my Mac, it came with Yosemite, so I'm not exactly an oldie, but I digress.

Some apps STILL don't support fullscreen mode, such as [MathMagic](http://mathmagic.com/). I find this quite irritating, and so I downloaded [Maximizer](http://chpwn.com/apps/maximizer.html), which was built for Lion, but which I thought would work in Yosemite. However, it doesn't. MathMagic still can't enter fullscreen. I have looked all over the internet for a solution, but almost all I've seen are for OSX Lion. What are my other options?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I gave MathMagic as an example only because it was the software that got me started researching on how to do this, but there are so many others. Adobe software is the de facto example of this. Adobe Flash, Photoshop, Illustrator, everything - all of them don't support Yosemite fullscreen. So, I was looking for more immediate options of making fullscreen work.

Answer (score 1):

Apps must be developed using [Apple's APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html) to use the modern full-screen mode.

InfoLogic, Inc., the developer of MathMagic, must incorporate these APIs into their next release to use the mechanism Apple has provided. You can [make a suggestion](http://mathmagic.com/support/suggestion.html) at the InfoLogic, Inc. site that they incorporate this handy view.

Comment: Yes, I made a suggestion to them before I asked this question, but I wanted to know if there were any more immediate options.